# How DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping works

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am confused about the way the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping works.

In my web.xml I have

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/somePath/someWork</url-pattern>

    <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I have the controller like this,

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/user/adduser", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public void addAdmin(@ModelAttribute("myData") myData data) {

        System.out.println("We reached adduser controller");

    }
```

And in the jsp file i have

```
<form:form id="adduser" method="post" action="/user/adduser" commandName="myData">
```

This does not work. I get the error no handler mapping found for "/adduser" and 404 for the page "/user/adduser"

But in the .xml file if i mention

```
  <url-pattern>/user/adduser</url-pattern>
```

it works, or if i make the controller like,

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/adduser", method={RequestMethod.POST})
```

also works. When submitting the page it reaches the correct controller.

I am now confused the way the @ReuqestMapping works. When a request comes like "/user/adduser" from where it will start looking for the right class and the right method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring will match against the `pathInfo` property of the `HttpServletRequest`.

If your `web.xml` specifies `<url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>`, then the `pathInfo` will be the path with the `/user` prefix removed, so the `@RequestMapping` has to be `/adduser`.

If `web.xml` specifies `<url-pattern>/user/adduser</url-pattern>`, then the `pathInfo` will be the full `/user/adduser` path, so `@RequestMapping` has to match against that.

This isn't done by Spring, but by the servlet container, and it can be a bit confusing at times.

You can mitigate against this by using wildcards in `@RequestMapping`, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="**/adduser", method={RequestMethod.POST})
```

Comment: Thanks for reply skaffman. This gives me the insight. Another relevant question. In the production environment people really do such mappings like <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> ? I have not seen any real example like this.

Comment: @kalyan: `*.do` is a hangover from the bad old days of Struts. You still see it on "real" websites, though.