# Using Spring's @RequestMapping with wildcards

Tags: spring, servlets, request-mapping

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740958/how-defaultannotationhandlermapping-works), but I am still confused about my situation. I want to map this ant-style pattern to a controller method:

```
/results/**
```

That is, I want any URL like `www.hostname.com/MyServlet/results/123/abc/456/def/` to go to this method. I have:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/results/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest() {...}
```

This works to guide the request to my method, but leads me to several questions:

1. What if I add another servlet mapping, like `<url-pattern>/another-mapping/*</url-pattern>`??? It will also get mapped to that method! How can I separate the two?
2. Why does the url-pattern `/results/*` work, whereas `/results/**` doesn't? According to ant path styles, `**` means to include nested `/` characters, whereas `*` stops at the next `/`. So, it should only successfully map a URL like `/results/123`, bot NOT `/results/123/abc/`. Right?

Comment: Just started a bounty on this. Look at my comments in the first answer...

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps in your servlet mapping you would want to direct all traffic to '/*'.  This way, you can distinguish in your controller what method to use with different @RequestMapping's.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/results/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleResults() {...}

@RequestMapping(value="/another-mapping/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleAnotherMapping() {...}
```

Hopefully the above will help with number 1.  As far as number 2 goes, I do not think that you can use 'ant-style' pattern matchers (specifically **) in your web.xml domain descriptor.

Comment: Hmm okay, I thought I had read that it uses Ant-style, but I guess I'm mistaken. So /* corresponds to nested /abc/123/.......

Answer (score 5):

> What if I add another servlet mapping, like /another-mapping/*??? It will also get mapped to that method! How can I separate the two?

With your current configuration you cannot. If you want to map `DispatcherServlet` to multiple URL patterns and distinguish between them, you can declare `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` with `alwaysUseFullPath = "true"` and use full path in `@RequestMapping`.

Alternatively, you can map `DispatcherServlet` as `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and use full path in `@RequestMapping` without reconfiguring `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`. Though in this case you'll need to [configre exclusions for static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129876/using-spring-mapping-to-root-in-web-xml-static-resources-arent-found/2129960#2129960).

> Why does the url-pattern /results/* work, whereas /results/** doesn't? According to ant path styles, ** means to include nested / characters, whereas * stops at the next /. So, it should only successfully map a URL like /results/123, bot NOT /results/123/abc/. Right?

URL patterns in `web.xml` are not ant-style patterns, so that only `.../*` and `*.xxx` wildcards are allowed in them.

Comment: Okay, so I added <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/> to my DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping bean. What should the @RequestMapping value be? Sorry, I'm new at this...

Comment: @Tony: It should be `/results/**`.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I'm getting: "No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/abc/123'"

Comment: Did you also change your web.xml domain descriptor's servlet mapping for MyServlet to '/'?

Comment: Okay so I have Dispatcher servlet mapped to "/", an @RequestMapping("/results/**") mapped method in my controller, and mappings on my default servlet for "*.html", "*.js", etc. Everything works except for URL's like "/results/123/abc", which give a 404. Any advice?

Comment: I have static .html pages that are served fine w/o mappings, and they also work without the explicit mapping * .html on my default servlet. However, I have a static .gif file in the same directory that isn't getting served. I also need to be able to use URL's like /results/abc/myImage.bmp, which I want to serve from a controller and not from static content (i.e. I need URL's ending in .bmp to be mapped to a controller IF the URL starts with /results/**, but serve static content otherwise)