# Spring RequestMapping with dash in url

Tags: java, spring, url, controller

I need to Map a URL eg. testdata-p-12345 in my Controller, currently im trying to do it with this mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/*-p-")
```

And for the first variable:

```
...
private static final String CODE_PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN = "{myCode:.*}";
@RequestMapping(value = CODE_PATH_VARIABLE_PATTERN, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDetail(@PathVariable("myCode") final String myCode, final Model model,

...
```

When im calling the following URL the controller does not get called, does Spring support dashes inside the request mapping, how should the mapping look?

https://localhost:9002/my/test-page/to/testdata-p-40022

Comment: Why you want ** before? Is it valid way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Spring's @RequestMapping with wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954793/using-springs-requestmapping-with-wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring supports dashes inside the request mapping. And your code works perfectly with the following call:

https://localhost:9002/my/test-page/to/testdata-p-/40022

Notice the additional slash between **-p-** and **40022**.

If you don't specify a leading slash in your request mapping path, the default request mapping handler will do it for you!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744010/7709086.

Answer (score -1):

you can set @RequestMapping with two or more vlue.

```
`    
@RequestMapping(value={"/hello","hello2"})
public Response hello(){
    return ok().put("hello", "hello world!");
}
`
```