# Can't map dispatcherServlet to context root

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

this is the current configuration i am using for spring mvc:

**1- web.xml:**

```
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/config/dispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

**2- dispatcherServlet.xml:**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />
 <context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**3- Controller: my web pages are under webapp folder directly**

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping("/search.jsp")
public String search(Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) {
          log.debug("Search Controller");
          return "search";
 }
```

ISSUE: when trying to access the search page as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyAPP/search.jsp
```

the controller is not invoked, but when i was mapping the dispatcher servlet to `/mapping/*` and accessing the search page as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyAPP/mapping/search.jsp
```

the controller was invoked correctly, i am using **spring 3.0.5.RELEASE**.

please advise, thanks.

Comment: In both circumstances, is the `search.jsp` page returned? From your question am I correct in thinking that the `log.debug("Search Controller");` only happens with one of the URLs?

Comment: @andyb,with mapping to / search page is rendered and controller is not invoked, and when mapping to /mapping/* controller is invoked and page is rendered.

Comment: Where comes this /mapping from ? Where is that namespace mentioned ?

Comment: @JeevanPatil the OP was describing something else that was tried in the `<url-pattern/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are forgetting about the built in default servlet configured in your web server/servlet container. For example in Tomcat7/conf/web.xml there exists:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which is catching the `*.jsp` before it ever gets to Spring. I tested this locally by removing all of the Spring configuration and could *still* get the `search.jsp`.

[How DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740958/how-defaultannotationhandlermapping-works) should be useful in explaining why this works they way it does.

When you had `<url-pattern>/mapping/*</url-pattern>` you created a more specific match than the simple `/` so requests were ignored by the default (i.e. Tomcat) servlet and routed to your correctly configured controller.

One way to fix this is to force everything through your servlet by using `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` but you will also need to make a few other changes to avoid mapping resolution problems.

I moved the *.jsp files into the (standard?) subdirectory `/WEB-INF` and added

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to **web.xml** and changed **dispatcherServlet.xml** to match like so:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

If you do not make these changes, a request to `/search.jsp` would be resolved by the InternalResourceViewResolver you configured to `/search.jsp` sending Tomcat into an infinite forwarding loop!

[No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/pages/apiForm.jsp]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266303/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-apiform-jsp) may be useful here.

*Aside: For most of my Spring XML configured projects I use `/WEB-INF/views` to keep the view layer separate from any configuration in the /WEB-INF root.*

Answer (score 0):

The following mapping will cause the dispatcher servlet to handle urls that were not explicitly mapped by other url mappings within web.xml.  Think of this as almost a catch all mapping, as long as the url was not handled by some other mapping.

```
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

When you configure the ViewResolver as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

The ViewMapping must point to a JSP within your project or else the catch all mapping provided for the dispatcher is going to attempt to handle the forward/redirect to the appropriate view.  You must make sure that a view exists within your project for the result of the viewresolver, which is `/search.jsp`.  This means there must be a search.jsp within the root of your projects web content folder.  It is much more common to see these views placed within the WEB-INF folder and a mapping of:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: when i changed the config, i get 404

Comment: if you change the config you need to have the search jsp within the web-inf folder