# Spring MVC Security Contraint - web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to secure my controller paths on Spring MVC as follows:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        metadata-complete="true">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/welcomePage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>myApp</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>allow all users</description>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>
                Encryption is not required for the application in general.
            </description>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <description>Role to allow authentication</description>
        <role-name>INTERNET</role-name>
    </security-role>

</web-app>
```

**myApp-servlet.xml (I'm excluding the bean tags so the dont take space)**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHome(HttpSession httpSession) {

        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
}
```

My home.jsp is located in /WEB-INF/views/

Right now even though I have logged, I am receiving a 403 status for the home.jsp

Is there a more appropriate way to isolate the *controller paths* and return the requested jsp's normally?

Comment: try to use spring security.. here is a helloworld http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/02/15/xml-config-based-method-level-spring-security-using-protect-pointcut/ & video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zu8COg80q4

Comment: This post should help you.

[Can't map dispatcherServlet to context root][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233337/cant-map-dispatcherservlet-to-context-root